# Preserve the state of rerender panel after navigating from page

Tags: rerender, cache

I've got a search results page that are rendered dynamically, from where user navigates to a result via

```
public PageReference displaySiteDetails(){
        try {
            selectedSite = sitesMap.get(Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('siteId'));
            PageReference pageSiteDetail = new PageReference('/apex/SiteDetail');
            pageSiteDetail.setRedirect(false);
            return pageSiteDetail;
        } catch (DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error.'));
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Where selectedSite variable values are rendered in SiteDetail page.

However, after clicking back, user is taken to a page where results in the panel are empty. Previously it was showing 'confirm form resubmit', which I've solved by enabling caching on apex:page tag via parameter cached="true", but I am wondering if I am missing something?

Comment: Do the pages you are navigating between leverage the exact same controller and extensions?

Comment: Yes, it is a same controller. One workaround I've found is apex:button to return a PageReference to initial page, but that does not work with browser back button.

Comment: Are you searching using JS Remoting/JS or using standard VF Tags.

Comment: Standard tags, using apex:commandButton and rerender="panelId". I've found a workaround to hijacking back button with JS and assigning it to server side action, but I do not like this solution.